# How does tag synonym affect top users list?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I read tag synonym's FAQ and related blog post but I probably missed one explanation. How does creating a tag synonym affect a top user list in both the master and the synonym tag? Are users' upvotes transferred from synonym to master tag?

Example:

- User have 150 upvotes in tag A and 110 upvotes in tag B (disjunct set of upvotes for simplification).
- Tag B becomes synonym of Tag A

What will be the result? A:150, B:110 or A:260, B:0? If the second is correct will it also remove a bronze badge for Tab B?

Comment: Thinking of making [entity-framework] shorter?

Comment: @Hans: yes it is related to [entity-framework] but I don't want to make it shorter. I will conclude this in separate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until the tag gets merged, they basically are considered two separate "top users" lists. So you will have A: 150 and B: 110. Post-merge, it'll then be A:260 B:0 because B will no longer have its own top users list.

Merging would indeed clear any badges earned. It may also result in new badges, though, if the combined score puts you high enough.

Comment: Interesting. So synonyms say these tags are same but each tag has its own "user league". How is then merging triggered? Do I at least understand it correctly that new questions are automatically retaged to the master tag? Can a user force the system to use a synonym? I think I'm going to read FAQs and blog post again.

Comment: @Ladislav Yes, the FAQs will have this but I'll give you a quick primer - "Merging is done by a moderator", "Yes, new questions get retagged even if the synonym tag is still alive", "Only by exploiting synonym chains, so in general no".

Comment: The latter point is that if A → B and B → C, then if you tag A you'll get B "illegally". This is why synonym chains are discouraged, of course.