# What happens to a tag badge when a tag is merged with another one, or it is deleted?

Tags: support, tags, tag-badges

What happens to the tag badges assigned to users, when the relative tag is deleted, or it is merged with another one?
Do the users keep the badge even if the tag doesn't exist anymore?

What happens when a user remove the vote for an answer for which the user has got the tag badge? Is the badge removed, if the user doesn't have the necessary number of votes for that tag?

Comment: You should get tag badge for merged one, if you don't have it already, IMHO. Badges would not taken away, unless moderators recalculated your badges, IIRC.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tag badges are the only systematically revokeable badges. They will be removed if you disqualify for the requirements, and the ensured non-existence of the tag is indeed a way to lose the badge. The same applies to vote undoing if you're right on the threshold, you would temporarily lose the badge. Better get that vote back!

That said, if it is merged rather than deleted, [you will probably get a new tag badge instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85164/how-does-tag-synonym-affect-top-users-list).