# Which questions count for the purpose of tag badges and dupehammer for the tag synonyms?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-badges, dupehammer

I have noticed that if two tags are synonymized then in the master tag only the questions/answers which actually have this tag are counted in the list of top users. The posts with the other (synonymized) tag do not count in the list of topusers. (This distinction is relevant only if the tags were synonymized without merging, i.e., the questions which had the other tag still have this tag, unless they have been edited. This is also confirmed here: [How does tag synonym affect top users list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85164))

Do the tag badges and dupehammer work in the same way?

- Do only questions with the master tag count towards the tag badges? Is it possible that some user can have both tag badges?
- For the purposes of dupehammer, the two tags are counted separately? If somebody gets dupehammer in the master tag, does that mean that they cannot unilaterally close question in the other tag (and vice versa)?

Based on various things about tag synonyms that I have read, it seems that for most purposes the synonymized tags count as two separate tags - the only difference is that one of the tags is automatically changed to the other one when a question is edited or when this tag is used in a new question. So it seems very likely that the two tags are considered separately also in connection with tag badges and dupehammer, but still it might be useful to have at least some kind of semi-official confirmation.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307207/3648282 ?

Comment: Here is a link to [meta.so] showing also the title: [Mjolnir doesn't work on old synonyms (should it?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307207) So that question gives answer for the dupehammer - at the tag badges and list of top users certainly work the same way.

Comment: Both URLs are identical, and you are allowed to answer your own question, if you agree that the answer is there; a cross-site duplicate can't be closed as a duplicate.